# How to change Firebase authDomain url to custom domain with DNS on cloudflare

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, dns, cloudflare

My current project setup for a react - firebase web app is as follows.

- Domain bought from godaddy
- Cloudflare DNS
- React web app deployed on google compute vm
- Firebase for DB , Auth and functions.

I have the following entry on cloudflare DNS
A record sub.mydomain.com pointing to google cloud vm ip.
A record mydomain.com pointing to another vm ip hosting public site on google cloud compute vm.

When i use google login, the sign in page shows the myapp.firebase.com which i supposed is because my firebase configuration has authDomain=myapp.firebase.com

If i want authDomain to be my custom domain firebase asks to add another A record for mydomain.com pointing to a firebase ip. 
I cannot have duplicate records pointing to different ip. Is the DNS entry required to change the authDomain or just the TXT entry (from step 2 of custom domain on firebase) is sufficient.
I do not intend to use firebase hosting.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  You'll probably get better results on superuser.com, or maybe serverfault.com.

Comment: You can have multiple A resource records pointing to different IP addresses. Most DNS servers will `round-robin` responses with a different IP address order in each request. https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/glossary/round-robin-dns/